# .python-eggs permission denied

Tags: python, database, django, terminal

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a simple db with Django. I'm the only user on this computer, so I should be an admin. How do I make it so that I have permissions so that Django can just do its thing?

here is some more of the error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/simplejson/tmpUxM60A.$extract'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

/Users/tyre77/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

Comment: what is the result of a `ls -l /Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/` and `ls -l /Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/` ?

Comment: for the first one:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  staff  102 Aug 30 20:58 simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp

Comment: "I'm the only user on this computer, so I should be an admin." Using an "admin" account doesn't give you write access to the entire filesystem, it just lets you use sudo to get root access. Using a normal user account with full access all the time is a huge security risk.

Comment: for the second one:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  staff  102 Aug 30 20:58 simplejson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files seem to be owned by root, and members of group staff do not have the rights to write into those files/directories and you're not root.

Try to change the owner of those files : `sudo chown -R tyre77 /Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/`

Maybe you've installed the module with a sudo command, so the files were created with the root privileges.

Comment: I think I did have to install using sudo because it denied me otherwise, but now I get this error 
    chown: /Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/: Operation not permitted

Comment: @Chris : even when running the chown with sudo ? oh, maybe it's the wrong order of args, try : `sudo chown -R tyre77 /Users/tyre77/.python-eggs/`